# How to make a registration by invitation at Bitrix?

Tags: php, content-management-system, bitrix

The registered user can give the link where you can register.
Without reference registration is impossible!
How is this done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has a ready Bitrix component -https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ua/solutions/altasib.invitereg/